# TeamSpeak 3 Disconnects

Tags: voip, connection, vps, openvz

I've recently had a few random TS3 mass disconnects and I'm am curious to know where I may find any applications that can help me determine the cause of any types of TS3 server disconnections as we plan on having many more users in the future. I run an almost empty VPS (OpenVZ) server with an ArchLinux template on it. I have 1.5/2GB of RAM, 2GHz of CPU and plenty of hard drive space, to run for the most part, just my TS3 and a low traffic apache web server.

This is what I am investigating.

```
2011-02-04 06:07:05.130343|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Valamoor'(id:224) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.131338|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Kevrow'(id:19￼ reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.191849|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'scuba'(id:200) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.192633|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected '[Ash] Setna'(id:75) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.193350|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Akiris'(id:254) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.194047|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Marcus'(id:25￼ reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 06:07:05.194726|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Guthry'(id:275) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'

2011-02-04 07:18:50.327071|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Valamoor'(id:224) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 07:18:51.339018|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Marcus'(id:25￼ reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 07:18:51.339870|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected '[Ash] Setna'(id:75) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-04 07:18:51.340515|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Guthry'(id:275) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'


2011-02-05 04:55:20.797353|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'JohnyRingo'(id:240) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-05 04:55:20.798517|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Maloo roots'(id:196) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-05 04:55:20.799314|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'Cpt dravyn'(id:234) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'
2011-02-05 04:55:20.839254|INFO    |VirtualServer |  1| client disconnected 'scuba'(id:200) reason 'reasonmsg=connection lost'

etc...
```

I need to determine if it is my hosting provider or my server, and what tools I can use to determine the issues.  My VPS host has told me this...

> "I checked out the node that your VPS
>   runs on and there is no abnormal
>   system load, or I/O wait from the
>   drive. I also checked the bandwidth
>   history from the server and there have
>   been no spikes or outages."

Answer (score 1):

In many VPS providers it is pretty common to have short breaks in network connections. This may happen because of bad connection or for example firewall, that is losing connection states for some reason. Also, this really do not matter with for example HTTP server, as browsers are making short requests and then opening new connections.

One way to figure out whether problem is in TeamSpeak or in connection is to keep some other TCP connection open at the same time, for example SSH. Please note that for example OpenSSH do not disconnect immediately when there is problems with connection, [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) does.

Comment: Do you know of any testing programs that I can leave running connected to the server other than TS3 that can test for short breaks in network communications?  See the problem is I rarely have a connection issue because I think I'm very close to the server, usually it happens to people futher away.

Answer (score 0):

Teamspeak 3 by default will want to use 20ms codec delay which is pretty aggressive, this can cause drops if the client or the server cannot keep up. Try using a higher codec delay on your channels somewhere around 40-60ms.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind and it is indeed helpful, but I wasn't having the issue on 20ms delay until I switched VPS hosts.